# Как на C++ сделать запрос SMART SSD&HDD?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, железо, hdd, диск

Не могу найти примеры как через C++ сделать запрос по SMART SSD&HDD?

Answer (score 1):

Для получения SMART-показателей в Windows используется IoCtl  [SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Реализацию на С++ возьмем из статьи [Hard drive information using S.M.A.R.T.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16671/Hard-drive-information-using-S-M-A-R-T) на CodeProject и слегка упростим. Для сборки понадобятся некоторые заголовочные файлы из Windows DDK (они также есть в архиве по ссылке). Получаем такой код (запускать с правами администратора):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <map>

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x500
//Windows DDK header files
#include "devioctl.h"
#include "ntdddisk.h"
#pragma warning(disable:4786)

using namespace std;
typedef map<DWORD,LPVOID> SMARTINFOMAP;

//SMART attribute constants
#define SMART_ATTRIB_RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE                    1
#define SMART_ATTRIB_THROUGHPUT_PERFORMANCE                 2
#define SMART_ATTRIB_SPIN_UP_TIME                           3
#define SMART_ATTRIB_START_STOP_COUNT                       4
#define SMART_ATTRIB_START_REALLOCATION_SECTOR_COUNT        5
#define SMART_ATTRIB_SEEK_ERROR_RATE                        7
#define SMART_ATTRIB_POWER_ON_HOURS_COUNT                   9
#define SMART_ATTRIB_SPIN_RETRY_COUNT                       10
#define SMART_ATTRIB_RECALIBRATION_RETRIES                  11
#define SMART_ATTRIB_DEVICE_POWER_CYCLE_COUNT               12
#define SMART_ATTRIB_SOFT_READ_ERROR_RATE                   13
#define SMART_ATTRIB_LOAD_UNLOAD_CYCLE_COUNT                193
#define SMART_ATTRIB_TEMPERATURE                            194
#define SMART_ATTRIB_ECC_ON_THE_FLY_COUNT                   195
#define SMART_ATTRIB_REALLOCATION_EVENT_COUNT               196
#define SMART_ATTRIB_CURRENT_PENDING_SECTOR_COUNT           197
#define SMART_ATTRIB_UNCORRECTABLE_SECTOR_COUNT             198
#define SMART_ATTRIB_ULTRA_DMA_CRC_ERROR_COUNT              199
#define SMART_ATTRIB_WRITE_ERROR_RATE                       200
#define SMART_ATTRIB_TA_COUNTER_INCREASED                   202
#define SMART_ATTRIB_GSENSE_ERROR_RATE                      221
#define SMART_ATTRIB_POWER_OFF_RETRACT_COUNT                228
#define MAX_ATTRIBUTES  256

#define INDEX_ATTRIB_INDEX                                  0
#define INDEX_ATTRIB_UNKNOWN1                               1
#define INDEX_ATTRIB_UNKNOWN2                               2
#define INDEX_ATTRIB_VALUE                                  3
#define INDEX_ATTRIB_WORST                                  4
#define INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW                                    5

//SMART structures

typedef struct
{
    BYTE m_ucAttribIndex;
    DWORD m_dwAttribValue;
    BYTE m_ucValue;
    BYTE m_ucWorst;
    DWORD m_dwThreshold;
}ST_SMART_INFO;


typedef struct 
{
    WORD wGenConfig;
    WORD wNumCyls;
    WORD wReserved;
    WORD wNumHeads;
    WORD wBytesPerTrack;
    WORD wBytesPerSector;
    WORD wSectorsPerTrack;
    WORD wVendorUnique[3];
    BYTE sSerialNumber[20];
    WORD wBufferType;
    WORD wBufferSize;
    WORD wECCSize;
    BYTE sFirmwareRev[8];
    BYTE sModelNumber[39];
    WORD wMoreVendorUnique;
    WORD wDoubleWordIO;
    WORD wCapabilities;
    WORD wReserved1;
    WORD wPIOTiming;
    WORD wDMATiming;
    WORD wBS;
    WORD wNumCurrentCyls;
    WORD wNumCurrentHeads;
    WORD wNumCurrentSectorsPerTrack;
    WORD ulCurrentSectorCapacity;
    WORD wMultSectorStuff;
    DWORD ulTotalAddressableSectors;
    WORD wSingleWordDMA;
    WORD wMultiWordDMA;
    BYTE bReserved[127];
}ST_IDSECTOR;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE  bDriverError;
    BYTE  bIDEStatus;
    BYTE  bReserved[2];
    DWORD dwReserved[2];
} ST_DRIVERSTAT;

typedef struct
{
    DWORD      cBufferSize;
    ST_DRIVERSTAT DriverStatus;
    BYTE       bBuffer[1];
} ST_ATAOUTPARAM;


typedef struct
{
    GETVERSIONINPARAMS m_stGVIP;
    ST_IDSECTOR m_stInfo;
    ST_SMART_INFO m_stSmartInfo[256];
    BYTE m_ucSmartValues;
    BYTE m_ucDriveIndex;
    char m_csErrorString[1000];
}ST_DRIVE_INFO;

typedef struct
{
    BOOL m_bCritical;
    BYTE m_ucAttribId;
    char m_csAttribName[100];
    char m_csAttribDetails[1000];
}ST_SMART_DETAILS;

#define DRIVE_HEAD_REG  0xA0

/*Global variables*/
SMARTINFOMAP m_oSmartInfo; //map для хранения SMART-показателей
ST_DRIVE_INFO m_stDrivesInfo[32]; //массив с данными о жестких дисках

/*Functions*/

//преобразование идентификатора SMART-показателя в строку
char* SmartIndexToString(BYTE index)
{
    switch (index)
    {
case SMART_ATTRIB_RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE   : return "RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_THROUGHPUT_PERFORMANCE   : return "THROUGHPUT_PERFORMANCE";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_SPIN_UP_TIME         : return "SPIN_UP_TIME";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_START_STOP_COUNT     : return "START_STOP_COUNT";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_START_REALLOCATION_SECTOR_COUNT      : return "START_REALLOCATION_SECTOR_COUNT";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_SEEK_ERROR_RATE                      : return "SEEK_ERROR_RATE";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_POWER_ON_HOURS_COUNT : return "POWER_ON_HOURS_COUNT";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_SPIN_RETRY_COUNT     : return "SPIN_RETRY_COUNT";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_RECALIBRATION_RETRIES    : return "RECALIBRATION_RETRIES";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_DEVICE_POWER_CYCLE_COUNT : return "DEVICE_POWER_CYCLE_COUNT";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_SOFT_READ_ERROR_RATE     : return "SOFT_READ_ERROR_RATE";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_LOAD_UNLOAD_CYCLE_COUNT      : return "LOAD_UNLOAD_CYCLE_COUNT";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_TEMPERATURE                  : return "TEMPERATURE";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_ECC_ON_THE_FLY_COUNT     : return "ECC_ON_THE_FLY_COUNT";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_REALLOCATION_EVENT_COUNT : return "REALLOCATION_EVENT_COUNT";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_CURRENT_PENDING_SECTOR_COUNT: return "CURRENT_PENDING_SECTOR_COUNT";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_UNCORRECTABLE_SECTOR_COUNT   : return "UNCORRECTABLE_SECTOR_COUNT";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_ULTRA_DMA_CRC_ERROR_COUNT    : return "ULTRA_DMA_CRC_ERROR_COUNT";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_WRITE_ERROR_RATE         : return "WRITE_ERROR_RATE  ";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_TA_COUNTER_INCREASED     : return "TA_COUNTER_INCREASED";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_GSENSE_ERROR_RATE            : return "GSENSE_ERROR_RATE";
case  SMART_ATTRIB_POWER_OFF_RETRACT_COUNT      : return "POWER_OFF_RETRACT_COUNT   ";

    default:
        return "";
    }
}

//вывод сообщения об ошибке
void ErrorMes(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    printf("%s failed with error %d: %s", 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);     

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);

}

//получение значения показателя из m_oSmartInfo
ST_SMART_INFO * GetSMARTValue(BYTE ucDriveIndex,BYTE ucAttribIndex)
{
    SMARTINFOMAP::iterator pIt;
    ST_SMART_INFO *pRet=NULL;

    pIt=m_oSmartInfo.find(MAKELPARAM(ucAttribIndex,ucDriveIndex));
    if(pIt!=m_oSmartInfo.end())
        pRet=(ST_SMART_INFO *)pIt->second;
    return pRet;
}

BOOL ReadSMARTAttributes(HANDLE hDevice,UCHAR ucDriveIndex)
{
    SENDCMDINPARAMS stCIP={0};
    DWORD dwRet=0;
    BOOL bRet=FALSE;
    BYTE    szAttributes[sizeof(ST_ATAOUTPARAM) + READ_ATTRIBUTE_BUFFER_SIZE - 1];
    UCHAR ucT1;
    PBYTE pT1,pT3;PDWORD pT2;
    ST_SMART_INFO *pSmartValues;

    stCIP.cBufferSize=READ_ATTRIBUTE_BUFFER_SIZE;
    stCIP.bDriveNumber =ucDriveIndex;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bFeaturesReg=READ_ATTRIBUTES;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bSectorCountReg = 1;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bSectorNumberReg = 1;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bCylLowReg = SMART_CYL_LOW;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bCylHighReg = SMART_CYL_HI;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bDriveHeadReg = DRIVE_HEAD_REG;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bCommandReg = SMART_CMD;
    bRet=DeviceIoControl(hDevice,SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA,&stCIP,sizeof(stCIP),szAttributes,sizeof(ST_ATAOUTPARAM) + READ_ATTRIBUTE_BUFFER_SIZE - 1,&dwRet,NULL);
    if(bRet)
    {
        m_stDrivesInfo[ucDriveIndex].m_ucSmartValues=0;
        m_stDrivesInfo[ucDriveIndex].m_ucDriveIndex=ucDriveIndex;
        pT1=(PBYTE)(((ST_ATAOUTPARAM*)szAttributes)->bBuffer);
        for(ucT1=0;ucT1<30;++ucT1)
        {
            pT3=&pT1[2+ucT1*12];
            pT2=(PDWORD)&pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW];
            pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW+2]=pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW+3]=pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW+4]=pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW+5]=pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW+6]=0;
            if(pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_INDEX]!=0)
            {
                pSmartValues=&m_stDrivesInfo[ucDriveIndex].m_stSmartInfo[m_stDrivesInfo[ucDriveIndex].m_ucSmartValues];
                pSmartValues->m_ucAttribIndex=pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_INDEX];
                pSmartValues->m_ucValue=pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_VALUE];
                pSmartValues->m_ucWorst=pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_WORST];
                pSmartValues->m_dwAttribValue=pT2[0];
                pSmartValues->m_dwThreshold=MAXDWORD;
                m_oSmartInfo[MAKELPARAM(pSmartValues->m_ucAttribIndex,ucDriveIndex)]=pSmartValues;
                m_stDrivesInfo[ucDriveIndex].m_ucSmartValues++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        dwRet=GetLastError();

    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bFeaturesReg=READ_THRESHOLDS;
    stCIP.cBufferSize=READ_THRESHOLD_BUFFER_SIZE; // Is same as attrib size
    bRet=DeviceIoControl(hDevice,SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA,&stCIP,sizeof(stCIP),szAttributes,sizeof(ST_ATAOUTPARAM) + READ_ATTRIBUTE_BUFFER_SIZE - 1,&dwRet,NULL);
    if(bRet)
    {
        pT1=(PBYTE)(((ST_ATAOUTPARAM*)szAttributes)->bBuffer);
        for(ucT1=0;ucT1<30;++ucT1)
        {
            pT2=(PDWORD)&pT1[2+ucT1*12+5];
            pT3=&pT1[2+ucT1*12];
            pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW+2]=pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW+3]=pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW+4]=pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW+5]=pT3[INDEX_ATTRIB_RAW+6]=0;
            if(pT3[0]!=0)
            {
                pSmartValues=GetSMARTValue(ucDriveIndex,pT3[0]);
                if(pSmartValues)
                    pSmartValues->m_dwThreshold=pT2[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return bRet;
}

BOOL CollectDriveInfo(HANDLE hDevice,UCHAR ucDriveIndex)
{
    BOOL bRet=FALSE;
    SENDCMDINPARAMS stCIP={0};
    DWORD dwRet=0;
    #define OUT_BUFFER_SIZE IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE+16
    char szOutput[OUT_BUFFER_SIZE]={0};

    stCIP.cBufferSize=IDENTIFY_BUFFER_SIZE;
    stCIP.bDriveNumber =ucDriveIndex;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bFeaturesReg=0;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bSectorCountReg = 1;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bSectorNumberReg = 1;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bCylLowReg = 0;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bCylHighReg = 0;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bDriveHeadReg = DRIVE_HEAD_REG;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bCommandReg = ID_CMD;

    bRet=DeviceIoControl(hDevice,SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA,&stCIP,sizeof(stCIP),szOutput,OUT_BUFFER_SIZE,&dwRet,NULL);
    if(bRet)
    {
        CopyMemory(&m_stDrivesInfo[ucDriveIndex].m_stInfo,szOutput+16,sizeof(ST_IDSECTOR)); 
    }
    else
        dwRet=GetLastError();
    return bRet;
}

BOOL IsSmartEnabled(HANDLE hDevice,UCHAR ucDriveIndex)
{
    SENDCMDINPARAMS stCIP={0};
    SENDCMDOUTPARAMS stCOP={0};
    DWORD dwRet=0;
    BOOL bRet=FALSE;

    stCIP.cBufferSize=0;
    stCIP.bDriveNumber =ucDriveIndex;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bFeaturesReg=ENABLE_SMART;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bSectorCountReg = 1;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bSectorNumberReg = 1;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bCylLowReg = SMART_CYL_LOW;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bCylHighReg = SMART_CYL_HI;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bDriveHeadReg = DRIVE_HEAD_REG;
    stCIP.irDriveRegs.bCommandReg = SMART_CMD;

    bRet=DeviceIoControl(hDevice,SMART_SEND_DRIVE_COMMAND,&stCIP,sizeof(stCIP),&stCOP,sizeof(stCOP),&dwRet,NULL);
    if(bRet)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        dwRet=GetLastError();
        sprintf(m_stDrivesInfo[ucDriveIndex].m_csErrorString,"Error %d in reading SMART Enabled flag",dwRet);       
    }
    return bRet;
}

//Считывает SMART-показатели для диска с указанным индексом
BOOL ReadSMARTInfo(BYTE ucDriveIndex)
{
    HANDLE hDevice=NULL;
    char szT1[MAX_PATH]={0};
    BOOL bRet=FALSE;
    DWORD dwRet=0;

    wsprintf(szT1,"\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE%d",ucDriveIndex);
    hDevice=CreateFile(szT1,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM,NULL);
    if(hDevice!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        bRet=DeviceIoControl(hDevice,SMART_GET_VERSION,NULL,0,&m_stDrivesInfo[ucDriveIndex].m_stGVIP,sizeof(GETVERSIONINPARAMS),&dwRet,NULL);
        if(bRet)
        {           
            if((m_stDrivesInfo[ucDriveIndex].m_stGVIP.fCapabilities & CAP_SMART_CMD)==CAP_SMART_CMD)
            {
                if(IsSmartEnabled(hDevice,ucDriveIndex))
                {
                    bRet=CollectDriveInfo(hDevice,ucDriveIndex);
                    bRet=ReadSMARTAttributes(hDevice,ucDriveIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hDevice);
    }
    else ErrorMes("CreateFile");
    return bRet;
}
```

Пример вывода в консоль показателей по первому диску:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    BOOL res = ReadSMARTInfo(0);
    ST_SMART_INFO * pSmart;

    for(int i=0;i<MAX_ATTRIBUTES;i++)
    {
        pSmart = GetSMARTValue(0,i);
        if(pSmart == NULL)continue;
        printf("0x%02x %s: %u\n", pSmart->m_ucAttribIndex,SmartIndexToString(pSmart->m_ucAttribIndex),(UINT)pSmart->m_ucValue);

    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```